# Friendly forwarding with a post request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, ruby-on-rails-4

I wrote a friendly forwarding feature for my app, but it fails on post requests. Scenario as follows:

1. User attempts to access protected page
2. App stores url and redirects to login page
3. User logs in and app redirects to stored url

sessions_helper.rb

```
def store_location
  session[:return_to] = request.url
end
def redirect_back_or(default)
  redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
  session.delete(:return_to)
end
```

application_controller.rb

```
def require_login
  unless !signed_in?
    store_location
    redirect_to signin_path
  end
end
```

sessions_controller.rb

```
def create
  ..
  sign_in user
  redirect_back_or root_path
  ..
end
```

This works fine, until you throw in `POST` requests.

1. User visits `posts#new` and submits form
2. App stores url and redirects to login page
3. User logs in and app redirects to stored url, **which fails**

`AbstractController::ActionNotFound at /forums/7/posts`

`The action 'index' could not be found for PostsController`

```
unless action_name = method_for_action(action_name)
  raise ActionNotFound, "The action '#{action}' could not be found for #{self.class.name}"
end
```

Any idea how to get around this issue?

Comment: do you really have `index` method in `PostsController` class? Can you please include the codes of `PostsController`

Comment: I don't, and I don't need one. Try submitting a form with validation errors in Rails, and look at the URL. `.com/posts/new` becomes `.com/posts` and this is why I'm getting the failure. I don't think I can use this method. I think I found the solution: My `store_location` method needs to check the request type, then either store the `request.url` or request.referrer` for `post`, `put`, and `patch` requests.

Comment: `.com/posts/new` works in `GET` method. When you hit the submit form it is sent in `POST` method. but in your case you are trying to access `/forums/7/posts` in `GET` method. When you access this URL in `GET` it will be routed to `index` action not to `create` action

Comment: Forget about my proposed solution, it does not work, for some reason. That's what I am trying to solve, by the way. How can I submit a form, have the user login, and come back to the form page? Instead of the `post` request itself?

Comment: Simply redirect user to `GET /posts/new` after.

Comment: OK, actually, my method does work. I was comparing `request.method` to lowercase strings, which fails as it's uppercase. Your idea does not work because redirecting needs to be dynamic. It needs to know when to go back to the referrer, on `post, put, patch` requests, and when to go to the requested page, on `get` requests.

Comment: sorry, i could not read your mind. however, it's great that you've sorted it out

Comment: No worries, thanks for chipping in. It's tricky because trying to access a protected page via `GET` is not the same thing as posting to a protected `action` via `POST`. If you want to access your edit profile page while signed out, you should be redirected to it after signing in. However, if you want to updated your profile after your session has expired, it should redirect you back to the form, after signing in (clicking `update` button inits a post request).

Comment: I guess, more succinctly, `redirect_to` issues a `GET` request. When you store the location after a form is submitted its uri will corresponds to a `POST` request. Using the uri with the `redirect_to` ends up sending you to the `index` action of the resource since it's a `GET` request.